# Interview questionUnable to perform action after visible element on page in Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In one of the interview asked If page loaded successfully element present on the page its visible but unable to perform action(like click) how to handle this scenario in Selenium WebDriver Using Java.
Can any one suggest how to handle this scenario without using JavaScript Executor.

Comment: Can you show your code along with the HTML?

Comment: Please add the html source code and your code. What action are you trying to perform? What exception do you get (if any)?

Comment: @Buaban , pburgr This question asked in one interview so i can not provide the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element is present and visible, but not clickable. You have to wait until it is clickable

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("the-element-id")));
element.click();
```

If it is not clickable because the element is covered by another such as an overlay element. You have to wait until the overlay disappears, or you may need to click on the overlay first.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("the-overlay-id")));
element.click();
driver.findElement(By.id("the-element-id")).click();
```